# dplyr::select() to reorder columns which may not exist

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

In dplyr, how can I reorder the columns of a tibble based on a character vector of columns names that contains variables that may or may not exist in the tibble?

I tried `select_if(names(.) %in% col_vector)`, but that doesn't reorder the columns.

Example:

```
set.seed(1)
col_order <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
tibby <- tibble(d = rnorm(10), b = runif(10), a = rnorm(10))

select_if(tibby, names(tibby) %in% col_order)
# A tibble: 10 x 3
#        d      b       a
#    <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 -0.626 0.935  -0.0449
# 2  0.184 0.212  -0.0162
# 3 -0.836 0.652   0.944 
# 4  1.60  0.126   0.821 
# 5  0.330 0.267   0.594 
# 6 -0.820 0.386   0.919 
# 7  0.487 0.0134  0.782 
# 8  0.738 0.382   0.0746
# 9  0.576 0.870  -1.99  
# 10 -0.305 0.340   0.620
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `intersect`

```
library(dplyr)
tibby %>%
     select(intersect(col_order, names(.)))
# A tibble: 10 x 3
#         a      b      d
#     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 -0.0449 0.935  -0.626
# 2 -0.0162 0.212   0.184
# 3  0.944  0.652  -0.836
# 4  0.821  0.126   1.60 
# 5  0.594  0.267   0.330
# 6  0.919  0.386  -0.820
# 7  0.782  0.0134  0.487
# 8  0.0746 0.382   0.738
# 9 -1.99   0.870   0.576
#10  0.620  0.340  -0.305
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
select(tibby, one_of(col_order))

         a      b      d
     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 -0.0449 0.935  -0.626
 2 -0.0162 0.212   0.184
 3  0.944  0.652  -0.836
 4  0.821  0.126   1.60 
 5  0.594  0.267   0.330
 6  0.919  0.386  -0.820
 7  0.782  0.0134  0.487
 8  0.0746 0.382   0.738
 9 -1.99   0.870   0.576
10  0.620  0.340  -0.305
```

Comment: Thank you! Interesting that `one_of` is retired in favor of `any_of`/`all_of`, which no longer reorder the columns.

Comment: Nice catch @Zian, looked it up and apparently `all_of` works as expected (like `one_of`) but `any_of` doesn't, so I expect that behavior will change. It's been flagged on the [tidyselect GH page](https://github.com/r-lib/tidyselect/issues/186).

Answer (score 1):

A way is to use `match` :

```
tibby[na.omit(match(col_order, names(tibby)))]
```

If needed with `dplyr`, it can be used as :

```
library(dplyr)
tibby %>% select(na.omit(match(col_order, names(.))))

# A tibble: 10 x 3
#        a      b      d
#     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 -0.0449 0.935  -0.626
# 2 -0.0162 0.212   0.184
# 3  0.944  0.652  -0.836
# 4  0.821  0.126   1.60 
# 5  0.594  0.267   0.330
# 6  0.919  0.386  -0.820
# 7  0.782  0.0134  0.487
# 8  0.0746 0.382   0.738
# 9 -1.99   0.870   0.576
#10  0.620  0.340  -0.305
```